# How to delete first row in excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have an excel file, i'm trying to read the first row pass it to another function and delete the first row from the excel and save it, until all the rows in the excel file are used up.

I tried using openpyxl i was able to delete the first row in my first attempt but when i try reading the excel file again it's giving me this exception

```
openpyxl.utils.exceptions.CellCoordinatesException: There is no row 0 (A0)
```

here's my code

```
import openpyxl

filename = "example.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
status = sheet['A1'].value
print(status)
sheet.delete_rows(0, 1)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: By "i'm trying to read the first row pass it to another function", you mean pass the data you read from the row to another function right?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Untested** but the following tweak should fix it. Instead of reading `'A1'` and removing row `0` you look for the first non empty row using `min_row` and read and remove that.

```
import openpyxl

filename = "example.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
status = sheet.cell(sheet.min_row, 1).value
print(status)
sheet.delete_rows(sheet.min_row, 1)
wb.save(filename)
```

Comment: I tried this, it's deleting the rows as expected but when it got to the last one, after deleting it, it still append the last row to the excel file and reading it again, i expect it to delete the last row too and end up with empty file.

Comment: I got a work around for this by making it check if the first row is equal to the last row, use the last row data and exit.

Comment: @sherlockholmes I would have suggested the same tweak. I never had a similar issue so had no idea that you couldn't remove the last row and have the worksheet empty. Would you mind editing my answer with your solution? It will be useful for any other user that will arrive here with the same problem

Comment: @sherlockholmes also, as a (small) performance improvement, you might want to read `min_row` and `max_row` only once, create a static variable for it and use a counter to increase `min_row`. This will work only if you do not have empty rows

Answer (score 1):

Once the rows are deleted with `delete_rows(beg_row, end_row)`, their index is also deleted, which means there exists no row with index `0` any more.